# Creating Oracle View or Procedure that returns a table with complex SQL, is it possible and how?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view

I have researched a few ways to try to accomplish what I want, but I am not sure where to start or what is the best way to get what I need.  I have played with a few different techniques, but am not sure I can accomplish what I need...

CHANGE TABLE

```
CHG_NUM | CHG_APP | CHG_DATE
CHG1234 | ABC | 01-MAR-2018
CHG1235 | ABC | 01-MAR-2018
CHG1236 | DEF | 03-MAR-2018
```

INCIDENT TABLE

```
INC_NUM | INC_APP | INC_DATE | INC_SEV
INC5678 | ABC     | 02-MAR-2018 | HIGH
INC5679 | ABC     | 03-MAR-2018 | HIGH
INC5680 | DEF     | 03-MAR-2018 | HIGH
```

I want to be able to loop through all the of the changes within the last x days and show all incidents that started within y days of the change with the same application and get a result that looks like this

RESULT

```
CHG_NUM | CHG_APP | CHG_DATE | INC_NUM | INC_APP | INC_DATE | INC_SEV
CHG1234 | ABC | 01-MAR-2018 | INC5678 | ABC | 02-MAR-2018 | HIGH
CHG1234 | ABC | 01-MAR-2018 | INC5679 | ABC | 02-MAR-2018 | HIGH
CHG1235 | ABC | 01-MAR-2018 | INC5678 | ABC | 02-MAR-2018 | HIGH
CHG1235 | ABC | 01-MAR-2018 | INC5679 | ABC | 02-MAR-2018 | HIGH
CHG1236 | DEF | 03-MAR-2018 | INC5680 | DEF | 03-MAR-2018 | HIGH
```

Comment: Couldnot understand the line `I want to be able to loop through all the of the changes within the last x days and show all incidents that started within y days`. Where you were able to loop ? Why the number of days are X days for one query and Y days from another. If you could show what you tried and whats not working with your try, that would be helpful

Comment: None of this requires any complex SQL. Please post what you have tried. Include setups of the tables, data and `plsql` source that represents what you have tried. The question as is currently, asks for someone to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I really understood your question here as I can't relate topic subject with actual content. Still looking at your dataset, you can try below query. Solution is very straight forward.

```
SELECT    CHG_NUM , CHG_APP , CHG_DATE , INC_NUM , INC_APP , INC_DATE , INC_SEV
FROM      CHANGE C, INCIDENT I
WHERE     C.CHG_DATE > SYSDATE - X --  x days put any number
AND       C.CHG_APP = I.INC_APP
AND       I.INC_DATE BETWEEN C.CHG_DATE AND C.CHG_DATE + Y -- Y days put any number
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Not relevant but a suggestion, Switch to `ANSI` joining technique rather than Old sql joining technique.

Comment: Thanks Vidya, what you sent over was exactly what I needed...Thank you so much!